# how should i decide which class is responsible of object creation?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

are there general rules, common pitfalls, about object creation responsability?
how should i decide who is responsible of object creation?
sometimes it is obvious, sometimes not, i'm trying to avoid redundant code and limit only to the minimum necessary.
what i should ask to myself when i have to decide where to write the creation method?

```
class State
{
    ...
    public [City] getCapitalCity()
    {
        return new City(this.capitalCityID);
    }
}

class City
{
    ...
    public static [City] getCapitalOf(State s)
    {
        return new City(s.capitalCityID)
    }
}
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A flaw of your first method is that it creates a new City object for every call. Something like that would be more natural to me:

```
class State
{
    protected [City] capitalCity;
    ...
    public [City] getCapitalCity()
    {
        if (this.capitalCity == null) {
            this.capitalCity = City::getCapitalOf(this);
        }
        return this.capitalCity;
    }
}

class City
{
    ...
    public static [City] getCapitalOf(State s)
    {
        return new City(s.capitalCityID)
    }
}
```

Note that I kept both methods in place but **delegated** one to the other. Another thing, which is still unsolved after this change, is that you won't be able to exchange the City object, i.e. for a mock in unit testing. The dependency is hard-wired.

Talking about design patterns, for a loosely coupled design the only classes that instantiate objects should be **factories**.

If we apply that here, it might look like that:

```
class CityFactory
{
    ...
    public static [City] createCapitalFromState(State s)
    {
        return new City(s.capitalCityID);
    }
}

class State
{
    protected [City] capitalCity;
    ...
    public [City] getCapitalCity()
    {
        if (this.capitalCity == null) {
            this.capitalCity = CityFactory::getCapitalOf(this);
        }
        return this.capitalCity;
    }
}

class City
{
    ....
}
```

For the sake of simplicity I kept the factory method static, in reality you would have access to some instance of `CityFactory`. And this could easily be exchanged to yield different objects.

> what i should ask to myself when i have to decide where to write the creation method?

**Two things:**

- do I introduce a new hard-wired dependency?
- could I extract object creation to an own class?

One could think that two domain objects like `City` and `State` are not the best example for decoupling exercises because they obviously will always be used together, right?

But if you think about it, it's not too far-fetched: Maybe at some point you will subclass or decorate your Cities to distinguish certain differences in behaviour. With a City factory you will only have to change the creation of cities at one point if you ever want to change it. And this is an important goal in OOD: if you have to change something, it should not be necessary to change it all over the place, but only at one point.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably say that it depends entirely on how your classes are going to be used. In this case, I'd opt for the `State.getCapitalCity()` since it's more likely that a developer's workflow would be to inquire what the capital city is of a state object they already have.

My class design would probably look similar to the following. That way, I can go back and forth between the two entities if need be.

```
class State
{
   ... 
   public City CapitalCity()
   {
      return new City(this.capitalCityId);
   }
}

class City
{
   ...
   public State State()
   {
      return new State(this.stateId);
   }

   public bool IsCapitalCity()
   {
      return this.isCapitalCity;
   }
}
```